# How can I create a group of same columns in each table in a database in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have almost 120 tables in my database. Recently for updating some business logic and control the flow user I need to update each table by adding 5 columns. Those columns are as below

> 1. IsActive
> 2. IsBlocked
> 3. IsVerified
> 4. CreatedByDate
> 5. LastModifiedByDate

I have tried this way for a single table, like `Users` table

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = 'Users' AND column_name = 'IsActive')
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD 
 IsActive bit NULL DEFAULT ((1))
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = 'Users' AND column_name = 'IsBlocked')
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD 
 IsBlocked bit NULL DEFAULT ((1))
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = 'Users' AND column_name = 'IsVerified')
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD 
 IsVerified  bit NULL DEFAULT ((0))
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = 'Users' AND column_name = 'CreatedByDate')
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD 
 CreatedByDate datetime NULL DEFAULT GETDATE() 
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = 'Users' AND column_name = 'LastModifiedByDate')
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD 
 LastModifiedByDate datetime NULL DEFAULT GETDATE() 
GO
```

But it is being really difficult for me to apply for all table manually by replacing the table name as it contain approximately 120 tables. So I am looking for a finest way to minimize this lengthy process or doing it through a smartest way. As I am obtaining the list of tables form my system table `sys.tables` so why not I will do it by a looping to minimize my work. Can anyone help me regarding this problematic issue?

Comment: exec sp_msforeachtable 'alter table ? add IsActive bit not null default 0';

Hope this will help

Comment: Can I just ask why you aren't using one Audit table linked back to the other entities? Can you imagine if you have to add another column in the future?

Comment: @MikeMiller Maybe this table would become too big eventually and difficult to deal with, given that every row of every table needs to end up there, together with the origin table name as an identifier..

Comment: you don't need an origin table name, just a guid,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done half of it. 
Now you only need to create your `ALTER` statements dynamically so that you get the table name from the list of tables in your database:

I would do this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
      , @tableName nvarchar(128) = 'category'
      , @colIsIsActive nvarchar(10) = 'IsActive'

      , @colIsIsBlocked nvarchar(20) = 'IsBlocked'
      , @colIsIsVerified nvarchar(20) = 'IsVerified'
      , @colCreatedByDate nvarchar(20) = 'CreatedByDate'
      , @colIsLastModifiedByDate nvarchar(20) = 'LastModifiedByDate'


select @sql = N' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = ''' + @tableName + ''''
             + ' AND column_name = ''' + @colIsIsActive + ''')'
             + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
             + ' ADD ' + @colIsIsActive
             + ' BIT NULL DEFAULT ((1))' 

select @sql
--exec(sql)
```

And this needs to be written 5 times inside a cursor where you read the names of the tables into `@tableName`. 
You will need to write exactly the same for the other 4 columns.
The cursor is not a problem in this case, you will run it once and it will go through 120 tables, not an issue.

I would declare 5 different `@sql` variables, to not have a looong long string generated in the end.

Below is the whole solution I am talking about:'

```
declare @sqlAddIsActive nvarchar(1000)
      , @sqlAddIsBlocked nvarchar(1000)
      , @sqlAddIsVerified nvarchar(1000)
      , @sqlAddCreatedByDate nvarchar(1000)
      , @sqlAddLastModifiedByDate nvarchar(1000)

      , @tableName nvarchar(128)  
      , @colIsIsActive nvarchar(10) = 'IsActive'
      , @colIsIsBlocked nvarchar(20) = 'IsBlocked'
      , @colIsIsVerified nvarchar(20) = 'IsVerified'
      , @colCreatedByDate nvarchar(20) = 'CreatedByDate'
      , @colIsLastModifiedByDate nvarchar(20) = 'LastModifiedByDate'


declare tables_cursor cursor for 
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='base table'
open tables_cursor
fetch next from tables_cursor  --start the cursor
into @tableName

while @@fetch_status = 0  --while there is a loaded record, keep processing
begin


select @sqlAddIsActive = N' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = ''' + @tableName + ''''
             + ' AND column_name = ''' + @colIsIsActive + ''')'
             + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
             + ' ADD ' + @colIsIsActive
             + ' BIT NULL DEFAULT ((1))' 

select @sqlAddIsBlocked = N' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = ''' + @tableName + ''''
             + ' AND column_name = ''' + @colIsIsBlocked + ''')'
             + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
             + ' ADD ' + @colIsIsBlocked
             + ' BIT NULL DEFAULT ((1))' 

select @sqlAddIsVerified = N' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = ''' + @tableName + ''''
             + ' AND column_name = ''' + @colIsIsVerified + ''')'
             + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
             + ' ADD ' + @colIsIsVerified
             + ' BIT NULL DEFAULT ((1))' 

select @sqlAddCreatedByDate = N' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = ''' + @tableName + ''''
             + ' AND column_name = ''' + @colCreatedByDate + ''')'
             + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
             + ' ADD ' + @colCreatedByDate
             + ' BIT NULL DEFAULT ((1))' 

select @colIsLastModifiedByDate = N' IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = ''' + @tableName + ''''
             + ' AND column_name = ''' + @colIsLastModifiedByDate + ''')'
             + ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) 
             + ' ADD ' + @colIsLastModifiedByDate
             + ' BIT NULL DEFAULT ((1))' 

-- to see what is generated: 
select @sqlAddIsActive  
select @sqlAddIsBlocked 
select @sqlAddIsVerified  
select @sqlAddCreatedByDate  
select @sqlAddLastModifiedByDate 

-- to execute, uncomment this after testing the select's
    --exec(@sqlAddIsActive)  
    --exec(@sqlAddIsBlocked)
    --exec(@sqlAddIsVerified)  
    --exec(@sqlAddCreatedByDate)  
    --exec(@sqlAddLastModifiedByDate)   

fetch next from tables_cursor into @tableName  --fetch next record
end

close tables_cursor   --close and deallocate
deallocate tables_cursor
```

> EDIT:

***Please note:*** **do not run** this on production. `ALTER TABLE` is a `DDL` operation that depending on the size of the tables, could take time. This needs to be tested on *dev/test* environments and only then it can be applied on production taking in consideration appropriate measures!

Comment: It's really helps me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use undocumented procedure `sp_MSforeachtable`
Example use case

```
USE AdventureWorks;
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'DBCC CHECKTABLE ([?])';
```

Where ? is table name. So I've rewritten your code a bit:

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable '
PRINT ''Adding new columns to ?'';

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''?'') AND name = ''IsActive'')
ALTER TABLE ? ADD IsActive bit NULL DEFAULT ((1));

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''?'') AND name = ''IsBlocked'')
ALTER TABLE ? ADD IsBlocked bit NULL DEFAULT ((1));

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''?'') AND name = ''IsVerified'')
ALTER TABLE ? ADD IsVerified  bit NULL DEFAULT ((0));

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''?'') AND name = ''CreatedByDate'')
ALTER TABLE ? ADD CreatedByDate datetime NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(); 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''?'') AND name = ''LastModifiedByDate'')
ALTER TABLE ? ADD LastModifiedByDate datetime NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(); ';
GO
```

`sp_MSforeachtable` will run through each table in your database and execute script that's within quotes, in order to inject table name to the script, simply use a questionmark (`?`). For instance the following would print each table in your database:

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable '
PRINT ''?'';';
```

So combining your given script and this, you can easily add new columns in each table.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please. I am not quiet getting it.

Comment: @lazycoder Yes, I can do that, give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This solution addresses a few things:

- skip the column loops, one `alter` per table
- generate code for all tables at once
- preview all of the code generated
- name the default constraints instead of using auto generated names
- wrap database identifiers in square brackets in case of [irregular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers)
- works for multiple schemas even if table names are the same
- use `not null` to prevent explicit `null` inserts
- use `not null` so default value populates for the column when added to the table
- use [**`datetime2`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) instead of `datetime`. I would actually recommend using [**`datetimeoffset`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) instead, but that is not a drop-in replacement for `datetime`.

---

For method, this uses the system views along with two [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

---

test tables:

```
create table a (id int not null identity(1,1))
create table b (id int not null identity(1,1), IsActive bit, IsBlocked bit, IsVerified bit)
create table c (id int not null identity(1,1), CreatedByDate datetime2(7), LastModifiedByDate datetime2(7));
```

code:

```
create table #cols (ordinal int, column_name sysname, add_sql nvarchar(max))
insert into #cols values
 (1,N'IsActive',N'IsActive bit not null constraint [df_$schema_$table_IsActive] default (1)')
,(2,N'IsBlocked',N'IsBlocked bit not null constraint [df_$schema_$table_IsBlocked] default (1)')
,(3,N'IsVerified',N'IsVerified bit not null constraint [df_$schema_$table_IsVerified] default (0)')
,(4,N'CreatedByDate',N'CreatedByDate datetime2(7) not null constraint [df_$schema_$table_CreatedByDate] default sysdatetime()')
,(5,N'LastModifiedByDate',N'LastModifiedByDate datetime2(7) not null constraint [df_$schema_$table_LastModifiedByDate] default sysdatetime()')

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
;with cte as (
select 
    o.object_id
  , schema_name = s.name
  , table_name  = o.name
  , c.*
from sys.objects o
  inner join sys.schemas s
    on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  cross join #cols c
where o.is_ms_shipped=0  
  and o.type = 'U' -- User Tables only
  and o.name in ('a','b','c') -- remove this line, it is for demo tables only
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from sys.columns i
    where i.object_id = o.object_id 
      and i.name = c.column_name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS) -- prevents collation mismatch if tempdb is a different collation
)
, code as (
select distinct
    alter_sql = N'alter table '+quotename(schema_name)+N'.'+quotename(table_name) 
  + N' add '+char(10)+'   '
  + stuff((
    select '  , '+replace(replace(add_sql collate Latin1_General_CI_AS -- prevents collation mismatch if tempdb is a different collation
       ,N'$schema',i.schema_name)
       ,N'$table',i.table_name
       ) +char(10)
  from cte i
  where cte.object_id = i.object_id
  order by i.ordinal
  for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,3,'')+N';'
from cte
)
/*-- preview of code by table, can not execute the rest of the code with this option uncommented 
select * from code;
--*/

select @sql = stuff((
    select char(10)+alter_sql
    from code
    for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'');

select CodeGenerated = @sql;

--exec sp_executesql @sql; --uncomment after reviewing code generation

insert into a default values; -- for demo tables only
select * from a;              -- for demo tables only
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TAWI65939

code generated:

```
alter table [dbo].[a] add 
    IsActive bit not null constraint [df_dbo_a_IsActive] default (1)
  , IsBlocked bit not null constraint [df_dbo_a_IsBlocked] default (1)
  , IsVerified bit not null constraint [df_dbo_a_IsVerified] default (0)
  , CreatedByDate datetime2(7) not null constraint [df_dbo_a_CreatedByDate] default sysdatetime()
  , LastModifiedByDate datetime2(7) not null constraint [df_dbo_a_LastModifiedByDate] default sysdatetime()
;
alter table [dbo].[b] add 
    CreatedByDate datetime2(7) not null constraint [df_dbo_b_CreatedByDate] default sysdatetime()
  , LastModifiedByDate datetime2(7) not null constraint [df_dbo_b_LastModifiedByDate] default sysdatetime()
;
alter table [dbo].[c] add 
    IsActive bit not null constraint [df_dbo_c_IsActive] default (1)
  , IsBlocked bit not null constraint [df_dbo_c_IsBlocked] default (1)
  , IsVerified bit not null constraint [df_dbo_c_IsVerified] default (0)
;
```

test results from table `a`:

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | IsActive | IsBlocked | IsVerified |    CreatedByDate    | LastModifiedByDate  |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | True     | True      | False      | 2017-06-21 14:55:30 | 2017-06-21 14:55:30 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

exec sp_msforeachtable 'alter table ? add IsActive bit not null default 0';

Hope this will help